# Cannot link docker container (rpi-nginx) to the local filesystem

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, docker, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi2

I'm playing with Snappy Ubuntu Core on Raspberry Pi 2 and Docker. I have created a container with [rpi-nginx](https://github.com/ckulka/rpi-nginx/) and it works but I have troubles with linking the container to the local file system. Following [this docker-nginx tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-run-nginx-in-a-docker-container-on-ubuntu-14-04) I linked *~/www* on my raspberry to */usr/share/nginx/html* on the container and created a file *a.html* in *~/www*. It looks ok because from the terminal I'm seeing *a.html* and defauld *index.html* on both places but when I try to open *a.html* from the browser 404 error occurred.
Wheat can be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to mount the right volume:

```
-v /full/path/to/your/www:/usr/share/nginx/html
```

Then track the logs once your container is launched:

```
docker logs <container name>
```

That will give you more clue as to why `a.html` is not served as expected by NGiNX.

Comment: The log looks ok. There is nothing about error or one of these directories. Paths are correct (I tried with full paths).

Answer (score 0):

This is what I see in both directories:

**RaspberryPi: ~/www**

```
drwxrwxr-x 2 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Aug 18 16:06 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Aug 16 19:05 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu   14 Aug 16 20:03 a.html
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root      7 Aug 18 16:06 b.html
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root    867 Feb 10  2016 index.html
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root    867 Aug 16 19:42 index.nginx-debian.html
```

**Docker: /usr/share/nginx/html**

```
drwxrwxr-x 2 1000 1000 4096 Aug 18 16:06 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Dec 30  2015 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 1000 1000   14 Aug 16 20:03 a.html
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    7 Aug 18 16:06 b.html
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  867 Feb 10  2016 index.html
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  867 Aug 16 19:42 index.nginx-debian.html
```

It's interesting that I can open only *index.nginx-debian.html* file. Even *index.php* returns 404.